# Github pull request review/approval tool

Tags: open-source, git, github

I’m trying to find some tools for pull request approval bot. i.e basically our idea is to trigger our CI for a PR only after the approval by commenting on the PR. I found a similar tool that matches my requirement [SavoLabs/github-review-bot](https://github.com/SavoLabs/github-review-bot) but it has some issue while deploying.

Can someone please help me any other similar kind of tool available for open source projects.